# MYSQL statement result from 2 colums depending on where

Tags: mysql

I want to make a query in PDO and give back the results to a JSON array to use it in an autocomplete. In the table there are 3 columns, like this

```
ID    |   Plaatsnaam      |   Alternatief
1     |   Beetgum         |   Bitgum
2     |   Beesterzwaag    |   
3     |   Beetgummermolen |   Bitgummole
4     |   Bierum          |
5     |   Birdaard        |
```

Now i want to write a query that give's back the plaatsnaam OR (!) the alternatief that starts with 'Bi', so the reult of the query has to be:

```
Bitgum,
Bitgummole,
Bierum,
Birdaard
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using two queries and use union to fetch all results.

```
  SELECT Plaatsnaam as rst from table where Plaatsnaam like 'yourinput%'
  UNION
  SELECT Alternatief as rst from table where Alternatief like 'yourinput%'
```

Comment: Of course, sometimes you don't think about the simple answers. Is there also a way that i can LIMIT the result (of both queries together) to 10 and sort the total result?